# can you create a lib or dll in VS 2005 and link with VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2005

I am using visual studio 2008 SP1.

And I am creating a desktop application using MFC.

I have a library I want to link with my application. However, the library was written in WIN32 visual studio 2005.

I am been having a trouble linking:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'AgentLib.lib'
```

I am wondering if it is because I am using MFC 2008 and the library was written and compiled with 2005?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added the path where your lib files are under project settings in Linker>General>Additional Library Directories

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem to do that.

You can either

- Add the directory where AgentLib.lib is to the library directories of your project.
- Add AgentLib.lib to your project (you may get a message box from Visual Studio asking for a rule, but there is no need for one, and it works)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. f you have issues please Check [this](http://groups.google.co.in/group/boost-list/browse_thread/thread/8aa48ca7a5b92807) links for some help. Also check for any dependent file which is being used by the lib created using VS 2005.